# To EJB3 or not?

Tags: architecture, ejb-3.0, pojo

I have an architecture scenario and I would like to discuss to get your opinion.

I can choose between these two (this is a constraint imposed on me)

1. Use EJB3+JPA - no Spring/Hibernate
2. POJO + JDBC - again no Spring/Hibernate

I have series of web applications (only intranet) that all need to be integrated. At database level, there will be 3 to 4 oracle databases (and about 40 to 50 tables per database). Some applications may interact with more than one database for some queries. Number of concurrent user(s) will be less than 100. User/audience per application will range from 10 to 6000 (max).

All applications will be deployed on one server, and it's very likely that database and server could be on the same machine.

Most of the use cases will be CRUD based (some can offer a good domain model for an ORM while others may not), with some business process, automated jobs etc There may be a future need to integrate with SAP for some applications.

Do you think EJB3 in this case will make the application more scalable or just add complexity? If I design with POJO, will an application of this I don't want to add complexity for no good reason. I tried to lobby for Spring and Hibernate but no success.

let me know if you need more details.

EDIT: I forgot to mention the application server. it's WAS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how JPA would be permitted, but Hibernate wouldn't. That doesn't make a lot of sense, given that Hibernate is a JPA implementation. Would another JPA implementation be OK, such as OpenJPA?

You haven't mentioned if you have an existing server, or will be installing your apps on a yet-to-chosen server. Has this decision already been made? If so, that may dictate your choice. A full, up-to-date JavaEE server will come with EJB3 and JPA implementations already.

If the server isn't an EJB3-enabled server, then EJB3 is much less compelling.

But if sensible technologies such as Spring and Hibernate have been ruled out, there always simple frameworks like iBatis that allow you to combine POJOs with JDBC.

Comment: WAS7 seems to be a JavaEE 5 app server, in which case it has built-in support for EJB3 and JPA. You should have no need of Hibernate. You should at least make use of the JPA support in the server, although whether you use EJB3 as well is less obvious (EJB3 and JPA are complimentary, but you can use JPA on its own).

Answer (score 2):

EJB and JPA are just interfaces; you'll still need someone to implement them. So if Spring+Hibernate aren't possible, then this means no JPA unless you can get an OK for another framework (... err ... Toplink, maybe? Is there *anything* which isn't Hibernate based?)

If you're stuck with POJO and JDBC, I suggest to look at [Grails](http://www.grails.org/). That will make your life much more simple.

Comment: The app server vendors tend to provide EJB3/JPA implementations - for WebSphere it's v7.0 and  in the EJB3 Feature pack for 6.1 and

Answer (score 1):

First level of discussion is to compare {POJO + JDBC, write persistence by hand} against {framework for peristence}. (I'd also suspect that you're going to end up with a need for interesting services, so I think EJB3/SLSB or Spring equivalent is relevent, even if you were to roll your own persistence).

So my belief is that persistence technologies (JPA or Hibernate) are now at a level where you need a good reason *not* to use them. hand-rolling crud JDBC is just routine work one should not have to do by hand.

As for the JPA v Hibernate and Spring v EJB3 debates, I'm much moe equivocal, seems to be an area with much religion.

Comment: There is no hibernate/spring in the debate. It cannot be used. It's between EJB3+JPA and none. I would like to know if I'm going to complicate things by choosing EJB3.

If I was allowed SPring+Hibernate, I would not have posted this question here :-)

Comment: I believe that JPA and hibernate offer similar levels of abstraction, and that using either is preferable to JDBC.

As far as EJB3 goes, as a mechanism for exposing services I believe it imposes negligale overhead over POJOs, and the wins in terms of transactions and security are worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Although your constrains are somewhat a contradictory (Hibernate is a JPA implementation after all) I would advice you to adopt a standard solution. If your only choices are a standard stack like EJB3/JPA vs. a handcrafted POJO/JDBC implementation I'd say go for EJB3.

When you take the POJO/JDBC road you'll probably end up creating your own Spring like - but less feature rich and less well tested - framework. Writing a custom framework is hardly ever justifiable for *application* developers.

Answer (score 0):

Just go EJB+JPA!

I guess you're stuck in some "corporate" env and you cannot use open source frameworks .. if this is the case I guess some IBM or Oracle implementation of the above interfaces is available - use it.

Answer (score 0):

WAS 7 defaultly has the OpenJPA implemenation provided. Spring+

Answer (score 0):

EJB3+JPA will make you work very simple..It's highy scalable and very easy to configure and use with each other.Creating entities is the toughest part but after that things go java wise(Specially if you use entities relationships)..I used spring and hibernate for 4 years and yes they are excellent if you don't have an application server. But as long as you have WAS 7.0 then i recommend using EJB+JPA.

Working with JPQL is far easier and reasonable to  java programmers. However; you can't call stored procedures unless you use JPA 2.1 which is supported only in WAS 8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple -
If jboss/glassfish, use EJB3
if tomcat, use pure JPA, or Hibernate or Spring data

EJB3 vs Hibernate? of course EJB3. You should know what EJB3 under jboss used hibernate, EJB3 under glassfish used eclipse link JPA.